How to send email from Yii2 through Google Workspace with Oauth authentication
Google says: "Starting on September 30, 2024, less secure apps, third-party apps, or devices that have you sign in with only your username and password will no longer be supported for Google Workspace accounts."
I.e. the way that I'm using in Yii2 to send out emails through my Google Workspace will not work anymore. I'm using currently the following settings:
'mailer' => [
    'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
    'useFileTransport' => false,
    'htmlLayout' => '@common/mail/layouts/html',
    'messageConfig' => [
        'from' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'charset' => 'utf-8'
    ],
    'transport' => [
        'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
        'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
        'username' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'password' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'port' => '587',
        'encryption' => 'tls'
    ]
],

What should I change and what should I configure in my Google Workspace. Thanks for any help.
